# recreating menu existing menu, adding drop down on one item

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have the following menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/home.png"  class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/me.png" class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/listeners.png" class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/favorites.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/notifications.png" class="menu_img" /></a> <span class="notification_badge_count"></span></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/settings.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/signout.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my css for this menu:

```
.menu {
float:right;
}

.menu_item{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
height:50px;
}

.menu li{
float:left;
height:25px;
padding:24px 10px 0 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px; 
}

.menu_img {
opacity:0.5; 
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Now, I would like to add drop down for one of the items in the menu, so I re-create the menu as follow:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/home.png"  class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/me.png" class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/listeners.png" class="menu_img"/></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/favorites.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/notifications.png" class="menu_img" /></a> <span class="notification_badge_count"></span></li>

<li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><img src="menu/arrow.png" class="menu_img" /></a>
<ul>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/settings.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="mylink.php"><img src="menu/signout.png" class="menu_img" /></a></li>
<ul/>
</li>
```

What changes I should I do to add the drop down on the arrow icon?

I could easily find copy paste menu, but then It will be more difficult to understand how the css drop down is created...

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ? I have removed images since i didn't have them. Instead, I have just put some text.
http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBJG/

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="mylink.php">
            HOME
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="mylink.php">
            ABOUT ME
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="mylink.php">
            LISTENERS
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="mylink.php">
            FAVORITES
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="mylink.php">
            NOTIFICATIONS
        </a>
        <span class="notification_badge_count">4</span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="#">
            ARROW
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="mylink.php">
                    SETTINGS
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="mylink.php">
                    SIGNOUT<img src="menu/signout.png" class="menu_img" />
                </a>
            </li>
        <ul/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
float:right;
}

.menu_item{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.menu > li.menu_item{
float:left;
height:25px;
padding:24px 10px 0 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px;
background-color:#f6f6f6;
position:relative;
}

.menu_item ul{
    display:none;
}

.menu_img {
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.menu_item ul{
    display:none;
}

.menu_item:hover ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:100%;
}

.menu_item ul li{
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    padding:5px;
}
```

**EXPLANATION**
The structure of css menus is generally as under :

  - MAIN MENU CONTAINER
- - MENU ITEM

    - SUB MENU CONTAINER
  - - SUB MENU ITEM

    - SUB MENU ITEM

If you followed till here, great!
Now all our main menu items need to be next to each other on one line...which is why you used float:left; That's the correct way. But .menu_item is also a class given to sub-menu-items. So I had e a few adjustments so that float:left is only taken by direct children of the main menu container.

Now the SUB-MENU in your case is a , which you have to bring under it's parent

For that, you position the parent

as **absolute** and position it's child -  - as relative and position accordingly using left and top value. top:100% would mean immediately under the main menu_item.

Now the menu_item in this sub-menu container need to be one below the other. For that, do not give float/position/display properties to these menu_items and the code works fine. (we did that before already)

I did a little CSS-play here with backgrounds and height to help you understand. Feel free to ask more questions. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Aditya. Thanks for your help. It works great. However, I still have small problem that I don't know how to tackle. When I use the code on blank page, code works. In my application, something hide the drop-down menu. It seems that the drop down is behind something, and is not shown. Is there any easy way to put the drop down on top, above of all elements??

Comment: Try using z:index property.
The maximum value to this can be 9999. You could try a safer value. for example, 100 or 200 to ensure this works for you.

Comment: Where should I add that property? on .menu_item:hover ul?

Comment: Thanks.. I found where the problem was...I had a div, named header_innder, which has overflow:hidden and height of 50px. Now I have to find a way how to fix that. But at least now I know how the menu work. Thanks for your great help.